# SQL Cursor - Count Each Occurrence in Group

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, fetch

Been out of the SQL world for a minute and need to know how I can change the below code to count each occurrence where code = 0 in each group where the id is the same and then proceed to the next group of id's.

Basically, I need a count of how many orders with the same id have more than one occurrence of code being 0.

Sample Data:

```
+------+------+
|  ID  | CODE |
+------+------+
| 1234 |    0 |
| 1234 |    1 |
| 1234 |    3 |
| 1234 |    0 |
| 1234 |    2 |
| 5678 |    0 |
| 5678 |    1 |
| 5678 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

My goal would give me a count of "1" for the above sample data.

```
Declare
n_id NUMBER;
n_code NUMBER;
N_COUNT NUMBER:=0;

cursor dups is
select id, code 
from process;

BEGIN

OPEN DUPS; 

LOOP

FETCH DUPS INTO N_ID, N_CODE;

EXIT WHEN DUPS%NOTFOUND;

  IF n_code = 0 THEN
    N_COUNT := N_COUNT +1;
  END IF;

END LOOP;

  IF N_COUNT > 1 THEN
   dbms_output.put_line ('Record: ' || n_count);
  END IF;

CLOSE DUPS;

END;
```

Comment: Your code looks like Oracle so I changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple query.  No need for a loop:

```
select count(*)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from process
      where code = 0
      group by id
     ) p
where cnt > 1;
```

If you want to print the value out in a PL/SQL block:

```
declare
   v_cnt number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into v_cnt
    from (select id, count(*) as cnt
          from process
          where code = 0
          group by id
         ) p
    where cnt > 1;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_cnt);
end;
```